# Gradle build seems to be stuck on processResources, any fix?

Tags: gradle

When building my project with gradle, it gets stuck on the processResources task.
I have a multi project setup: i have a root with under that 3 projects: adminutils-common, adminutils-fabric and adminutils-bukkit.
When i run the build task, it works, until it gets to any of the processResources tasks, it just stays on that task forever, it just never stops, one time it was still on the task after 18 minutes.
It also does this if i somehow skip adminutils-bukkit and it gets to adminutils-fabric. When i run it with
–debug it constantly logs this:

```
2024-02-03T22:40:27.531+0100 [DEBUG] [jdk.internal.httpclient.debug] [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [1046s 841ms] HttpClientImpl(1) next timeout: 0
2024-02-03T22:40:27.531+0100 [DEBUG] [jdk.internal.httpclient.debug] [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [1046s 842ms] HttpClientImpl(1) next expired: 0
2024-02-03T22:40:27.531+0100 [DEBUG] [jdk.internal.httpclient.debug] [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [1046s 842ms] HttpClientImpl(1) Next deadline is 3000
2024-02-03T22:40:30.540+0100 [DEBUG] [jdk.internal.httpclient.debug] [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [1049s 850ms] HttpClientImpl(1) next timeout: 0
2024-02-03T22:40:30.540+0100 [DEBUG] [jdk.internal.httpclient.debug] [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [1049s 850ms] HttpClientImpl(1) next expired: 0
2024-02-03T22:40:30.540+0100 [DEBUG] [jdk.internal.httpclient.debug] [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [1049s 850ms] HttpClientImpl(1) Next deadline is 3000
2024-02-03T22:40:33.002+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Daemon worker: acquired lock on worker lease
2024-02-03T22:40:33.002+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Daemon worker: released lock on worker lease
2024-02-03T22:40:33.002+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] included builds: acquired lock on worker lease
2024-02-03T22:40:33.002+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] included builds: released lock on worker lease
2024-02-03T22:40:33.002+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Execution worker Thread 10: acquired lock on worker lease
2024-02-03T22:40:33.002+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Execution worker Thread 10: released lock on worker lease
2024-02-03T22:40:33.002+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Execution worker Thread 11: acquired lock on worker lease
2024-02-03T22:40:33.002+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Execution worker Thread 11: released lock on worker lease
2024-02-03T22:40:33.002+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Execution worker: acquired lock on worker lease
2024-02-03T22:40:33.002+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Execution worker: released lock on worker lease
2024-02-03T22:40:33.002+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Execution worker Thread 4: acquired lock on worker lease
2024-02-03T22:40:33.002+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Execution worker Thread 4: released lock on worker lease
2024-02-03T22:40:33.002+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Execution worker Thread 5: acquired lock on worker lease
2024-02-03T22:40:33.002+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Execution worker Thread 5: released lock on worker lease
2024-02-03T22:40:33.002+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Execution worker Thread 3: acquired lock on worker lease
2024-02-03T22:40:33.002+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Execution worker Thread 3: released lock on worker lease
2024-02-03T22:40:33.003+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Execution worker Thread 6: acquired lock on worker lease
2024-02-03T22:40:33.003+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Execution worker Thread 6: released lock on worker lease
2024-02-03T22:40:33.003+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Execution worker Thread 7: acquired lock on worker lease
2024-02-03T22:40:33.003+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Execution worker Thread 7: released lock on worker lease
2024-02-03T22:40:33.003+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Execution worker Thread 8: acquired lock on worker lease
2024-02-03T22:40:33.003+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Execution worker Thread 8: released lock on worker lease
2024-02-03T22:40:33.003+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Execution worker Thread 9: acquired lock on worker lease
2024-02-03T22:40:33.003+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Execution worker Thread 9: released lock on worker lease
2024-02-03T22:40:33.546+0100 [DEBUG] [jdk.internal.httpclient.debug] [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [1052s 855ms] HttpClientImpl(1) next timeout: 0
2024-02-03T22:40:33.546+0100 [DEBUG] [jdk.internal.httpclient.debug] [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [1052s 855ms] HttpClientImpl(1) next expired: 0
2024-02-03T22:40:33.546+0100 [DEBUG] [jdk.internal.httpclient.debug] [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [1052s 856ms] HttpClientImpl(1) Next deadline is 3000
2024-02-03T22:40:36.546+0100 [DEBUG] [jdk.internal.httpclient.debug] [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [1055s 855ms] HttpClientImpl(1) next timeout: 0
2024-02-03T22:40:36.546+0100 [DEBUG] [jdk.internal.httpclient.debug] [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [1055s 856ms] HttpClientImpl(1) next expired: 0
2024-02-03T22:40:36.546+0100 [DEBUG] [jdk.internal.httpclient.debug] [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [1055s 856ms] HttpClientImpl(1) Next deadline is 3000
2024-02-03T22:40:36.794+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
2024-02-03T22:40:36.794+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2024-02-03T22:40:36.794+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
2024-02-03T22:40:36.795+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
2024-02-03T22:40:36.795+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2024-02-03T22:40:36.795+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
2024-02-03T22:40:39.551+0100 [DEBUG] [jdk.internal.httpclient.debug] [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [1058s 860ms] HttpClientImpl(1) next timeout: 0
2024-02-03T22:40:39.551+0100 [DEBUG] [jdk.internal.httpclient.debug] [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [1058s 860ms] HttpClientImpl(1) next expired: 0
2024-02-03T22:40:39.551+0100 [DEBUG] [jdk.internal.httpclient.debug] [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [1058s 860ms] HttpClientImpl(1) Next deadline is 3000
2024-02-03T22:40:42.556+0100 [DEBUG] [jdk.internal.httpclient.debug] [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [1061s 865ms] HttpClientImpl(1) next timeout: 0
2024-02-03T22:40:42.556+0100 [DEBUG] [jdk.internal.httpclient.debug] [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [1061s 865ms] HttpClientImpl(1) next expired: 0
2024-02-03T22:40:42.556+0100 [DEBUG] [jdk.internal.httpclient.debug] [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [1061s 865ms] HttpClientImpl(1) Next deadline is 3000
2024-02-03T22:40:45.558+0100 [DEBUG] [jdk.internal.httpclient.debug] [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [1064s 867ms] HttpClientImpl(1) next timeout: 0
2024-02-03T22:40:45.558+0100 [DEBUG] [jdk.internal.httpclient.debug] [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [1064s 868ms] HttpClientImpl(1) next expired: 0
2024-02-03T22:40:45.558+0100 [DEBUG] [jdk.internal.httpclient.debug] [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [1064s 868ms] HttpClientImpl(1) Next deadline is 3000
2024-02-03T22:40:46.783+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
2024-02-03T22:40:46.783+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2024-02-03T22:40:46.784+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
2024-02-03T22:40:46.785+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
2024-02-03T22:40:46.785+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2024-02-03T22:40:46.785+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
2024-02-03T22:40:48.573+0100 [DEBUG] [jdk.internal.httpclient.debug] [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [1067s 882ms] HttpClientImpl(1) next timeout: 0
2024-02-03T22:40:48.573+0100 [DEBUG] [jdk.internal.httpclient.debug] [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [1067s 883ms] HttpClientImpl(1) next expired: 0
2024-02-03T22:40:48.573+0100 [DEBUG] [jdk.internal.httpclient.debug] [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [1067s 883ms] HttpClientImpl(1) Next deadline is 3000
2024-02-03T22:40:51.587+0100 [DEBUG] [jdk.internal.httpclient.debug] [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [1070s 896ms] HttpClientImpl(1) next timeout: 0
2024-02-03T22:40:51.587+0100 [DEBUG] [jdk.internal.httpclient.debug] [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [1070s 896ms] HttpClientImpl(1) next expired: 0
2024-02-03T22:40:51.587+0100 [DEBUG] [jdk.internal.httpclient.debug] [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [1070s 896ms] HttpClientImpl(1) Next deadline is 3000
2024-02-03T22:40:54.600+0100 [DEBUG] [jdk.internal.httpclient.debug] [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [1073s 909ms] HttpClientImpl(1) next timeout: 0
2024-02-03T22:40:54.600+0100 [DEBUG] [jdk.internal.httpclient.debug] [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [1073s 909ms] HttpClientImpl(1) next expired: 0
2024-02-03T22:40:54.600+0100 [DEBUG] [jdk.internal.httpclient.debug] [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [1073s 909ms] HttpClientImpl(1) Next deadline is 3000
2024-02-03T22:40:56.781+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
2024-02-03T22:40:56.782+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2024-02-03T22:40:56.782+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
2024-02-03T22:40:56.783+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
2024-02-03T22:40:56.783+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2024-02-03T22:40:56.783+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
2024-02-03T22:40:57.602+0100 [DEBUG] [jdk.internal.httpclient.debug] [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [1076s 910ms] HttpClientImpl(1) next timeout: 0
2024-02-03T22:40:57.602+0100 [DEBUG] [jdk.internal.httpclient.debug] [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [1076s 910ms] HttpClientImpl(1) next expired: 0
2024-02-03T22:40:57.602+0100 [DEBUG] [jdk.internal.httpclient.debug] [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [1076s 910ms] HttpClientImpl(1) Next deadline is 3000
2024-02-03T22:41:00.610+0100 [DEBUG] [jdk.internal.httpclient.debug] [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [1079s 919ms] HttpClientImpl(1) next timeout: 0
2024-02-03T22:41:00.610+0100 [DEBUG] [jdk.internal.httpclient.debug] [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [1079s 919ms] HttpClientImpl(1) next expired: 0
2024-02-03T22:41:00.610+0100 [DEBUG] [jdk.internal.httpclient.debug] [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [1079s 919ms] HttpClientImpl(1) Next deadline is 3000
```

Here is the folder structure of my project:
[Project Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWErR.png)
[Here](https://gist.github.com/electricsteve/2a6ef39a662e1562d1add93e02662f57) is a gist with some important files, does someone know why it’s getting stuck?

I also tried removing everything in the processResources block, that didn't work, but when i removed the block entirely, it did work, but i dont want that, i want to process the files.
Bit late but here is also the contents of the plugin.yml and fabric.mod.json files:
Fabric.mod.json

```json
{
  "schemaVersion": 1,
  "id": "adminutils",
  "version": "${version}",
  "name": "AdminUtils",
  "description": "",
  "authors": [],
  "contact": {
    "repo": "https://github.com/electricsteve/AdminUtils"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "icon": "assets/adminutils/icon.png",
  "environment": "client",
  "entrypoints": {
    "client": [
      "electricsteve.adminutils.client.AdminUtilsFabricClient"
    ],
    "main": [
      "electricsteve.adminutils.AdminUtilsFabric"
    ]
  },
  "mixins": [
    "adminutils.mixins.json"
  ],
  "depends": {
    "fabricloader": ">=${loader_version}",
    "fabric": "*",
    "minecraft": "${minecraft_version}"
  }
}
```

Plugin.yml

```yaml
name: AdminUtils
version: '${version}'
main: electricsteve.adminutils.AdminUtilsBukkit
api-version: '1.20'
```

Comment: I think you need to share the specification of your `processResources` tasks to shed some more light on the problem. If that's too much code, you could try running different individual `processResources` tasks one by one to narrow down where the issue is

Comment: @SimonJacobs The processResources task can be seen in the gist

Comment: Ah I missed that. Also I think we need to see the contents of `fabric.mod.json` and `paper-plugin.yml`. Please post these (and your processResources task definitions) in the question as all detail is supposed to be in the question so it's useful to others (see eg https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252693/is-it-ok-to-post-gists-instead-of-copying-the-code?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.